# string comparision inside a file in python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to write a script in python for finding the output of line 7 which is "y" if my first line is true (6c00ff00 = 1). I am able capture all these values in a file (say "xyz") but I am unable to compare in the file.

```
>>> vi xyz

6c00ff00 = 1
6c01ff00 = BGSV 1
6c02ff00 = 08IS01191025
6c03ff00 = 192.11.13.5
7005ff00 = g430
e808ff00 = 249
6c0aff00 = y
7002ff00 = 35 .4  .0  /
7001ff00 = 0
7b00ff00 =
7100ff00 = 1
7003ff00 = 192.11.13.150
```

Comment: And if your first line is false?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('xyz') as infile:
  line1 = infile.readline().strip()
  for _ in xrange(6):
    line7 = infile.readline()
  line7 = line7.strip()
  print "The first line is '%s'" %line1
  print "The seventh line is '%s'" %line7
  if line1.split('=')[1].strip() == '1':
    if line7.split('=')[1].strip() == 'y':
      print "Correct"
    else:
      print "Wrong"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.... i am geting an error while doing as above...    File "./scr.py", line 14
    if line1.split('=')[1].strip() == '1'
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  could you please help

Comment: @user2885062: There was a missing `:`. It's fixed now. Check out the edit